# Flutter transform creates an unwanted white space. Alternatives?

Tags: flutter

I have a screen that contains an image and underneath a container with a white background, the whole thing is contained in a ListView. I want the container to have a rounded border and be slightly above the image.

I have used the following code:

```
 Scaffold(
    body: ListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
      children: [
          widget for the image,
          Container(
              transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, -30.0, 0.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
```

but this causes empty space at the end of the container with a white background, instead I want it to occupy all the space until the end of the screen. The transform attribute only moves upwards, I want to expand the container upwards instead.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To put a widget above another widget you have to put both widgets in a `Stack` widget, and use positioned for one of them or both.

example

```dart
    const double imageHeight = 200;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          // widget for the image,
          Container(
            height: imageHeight,
            child: Image.asset('your_image_path_here'),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: imageHeight - 30, // Adjust as needed
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  // widgets
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```